# Initialize variable if class method is run

Tags: python, oop

I have a class, like

```
class D:
    def __init__(self):
        """some variables"""
    def foo(self):
        """generates lots of data"""
```

I would like to be able to store all of the data that `foo` creates within the instance of the class that `foo` is being called from. Almost like creating a new initialization variable, but only once the method is called. For if the user never calls `foo`, no need to have generated the data to begin with.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can bind new attributes to the instance in form of the generated data in `foo` when the method is called the first time, and avoid those in subsequent calls by setting say a flag attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about to make a flag which will say if data was already generated?

```
class D:
    def __init__(self):
        self.already_generated = False
        """some variables"""
    def foo(self):
        """generates lots of data"""
        if not already_generated:
            self.generate()...
            already_generated = True

    def generate(self,...):
```

Comment: your comment made me think, I could just do `self.data = None`, and then just check to see if it is `None` and set it to the data when that function is called. Good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you're trying to do, but if you want a class method to generate data that can be accessed from that instance you can put it into a data structure that is a member of that class:

```
class D:
    def __init__(self):
        #class member variables here
        self.fooArray = []
    def foo(self):
        #insert your data to self.fooArray here, eg:
        for i in range(1, 10000):
            self.fooArray.append(i)
```

Comment: You probably want `self.fooArray` when you make it